# Projective line intersecting 3 projective subspaces

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I am trying to solve the following problem:

---

Let $\mathbb{P}(U),$ $\mathbb{P}(V)$ and $\mathbb{P}(W)$ be projective subspaces of dimension $k,$ $l$ and $m$ respectively in $\mathbb{P}_K^n$.

Suppose $k+l+m\geq n-1$. Prove that there is a projective line intersecting all 3 subspaces.

---

So if $\mathbb{P}(U)\cap \mathbb{P}(V)\neq \emptyset,$ then it's easy because we just take any (projective) point in their intersection and any (projective) point in $\mathbb{P}(W)$ and form the projective line between them.

If $\mathbb{P}(U)\cap \mathbb{P}(V)=\emptyset,$ then $U\cap V=\{0\}$ and so $\dim(U + V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)$ and so
$$\dim((U+V)\cap W)=k+l+m+3-\dim(U+V+W)\geq (k+l+m-(n-1))+1\geq 1$$
hence $\mathbb{P}(U+V)$ intersects $\mathbb{P}(U),$ $\mathbb{P}(V)$ and $\mathbb{P}(W)$ but it might not be a line... so now I'm stuck.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dear user234559, your displayed line is false: you are mixing up  vector dimension and projective dimension. A  counterexample already arises with  $n=1, k=l=m=0$.

Comment: Oh yes - sorry - I will fix this...

Comment: this is now correct, right?

Answer (score 2):

I've only got time to outline this, but here we go...

We have subspaces $U, V, W$ of $K^{n+1}$, of dimension $\tilde k = k+1, \tilde l = l+1$, and $\tilde m = m+1$ respectively, with $\tilde k + \tilde l + \tilde m \geq n + 2$.

First, note that if any two subspaces have a non-zero vector in common, we are done, because their projectivisations intersect, and we can just take a line from this intersection to any point of the third subspace.  So assume that $U \oplus V \hookrightarrow K^{n+1}$.  Now, $\dim (K^{n+1} / (U \oplus V)) = n+1 - \tilde k - \tilde l \leq \tilde m - 1 = \dim W - 1$.  So there is at least one vector $w \in W \cap ( U \oplus V)$.  Write $w = u + v$, with $u \in U, v \in V$.  Assume $u \neq 0$ and $v\neq 0$, because otherwise $w \in V$ or $w \in U$, and we have already dealt with that case.

$w, u, v$ span a two-dimensional subspace, and upon projectivisation, this gives a line that intersects all three subspaces of interest.

Comment: Dear Georges, hasn't Rhys accounted for this in his last comment in brackets: "(Actually, the above assumes that both u and v are non-zero, but if one of them is zero, then $w\in U$ or $w\in V$)" ?

Comment: Yes, I thought I accounted for it. :-)
I wrote this answer quickly, so it may not be laid out perfectly, but at least it's correct, and it's elementary, which I think is what the question was looking for.  I'll move the parenthetical comment into the main body of the answer to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Dear Rhys, your answer is perfectly correct and elementary, just as elliptic2005 required: bravo and +1. Apologies for my former, unjustified, skepticism.

Comment: Dear Elliptic2005: I suggest you accept Rhys's great answer by clicking on the check sign in the margin of his answer.

Comment: No problem, Georges; comments are good to sort these things out.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to the problem is to use the [Schubert calculus](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/schubertcalculusreview.pdf) in the grassmannian $\mathbb G=\mathbb G(1,\mathbb P^n)$ of lines in $\mathbb P^n$.
That grassmannian has dimension $2n-2$ and the set of lines intersecting $\mathbb P(U)$ is a subvariety $\Omega _{n-1-k}$ (this is a standard notation) of codimension $ n-1-m$ in $\mathbb G$.
The lines intersecting $\mathbb P(V)$ and $\mathbb P(W)$ similarly form subvarieties $\Omega _{n-1-l}, \Omega _{n-1-m}$ of codimensions $n-1-l$ and $n-1-m$.
 [Pieri's formula](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/665/Sept24.pdf)  implies that the intersection of those three $\Omega$ 's is non empty as soon as  $$  (n-1-k)+(n-1-l)+(n-1-m) \leq \dim \mathbb G=2n-2               $$ and this is true according to your hypothesis.
Any point  $\omega\in \Omega _{n-1-k}\cap\Omega _{n-1-l}\cap\Omega _{n-1-m}$ in this intersection then represents a line $L_\omega\subset \mathbb P^n$ cutting all three of   $\mathbb{P}(U),\mathbb{P}(V)$ and $\mathbb{P}(W)$.

**Edit**
What I wrote applies to the context of the question but should not be unduly generalized: it is **not** true that arbitrary subvarieties of a grassmannian $\mathbb G$ whose dimensions sum to at most  $\dim \mathbb G$ have a non-empty intersection.
For example in  $\mathbb G=\mathbb G(1,\mathbb P^3)$ consider the subvariety $\Omega_2\subset \mathbb G$ of projective lines containing some point $q\in \mathbb P^3$ and the subvariety $\Omega_{(1,1)}\subset \mathbb G$ of projective lines contained in some projective plane $\mathbb P\subset \mathbb P^3$ such that  $q\notin \mathbb P$.
Obviously $\Omega_2\cap \Omega_{(1,1)}=\emptyset$:  indeed since $q\notin \mathbb P$ no projective line $L\subset \mathbb P$ can satisfy  $L\supset q$.
Nevertheless $\dim \Omega_2+\dim \Omega_{(1,1)}=2+2=4=\dim \mathbb G$

To say it more forcefully: **Bézout's theorem does not hold in Grassmannians**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was looking for something a little more elementary - this is my first course in algebraic geometry and we only covered very basic things...

Comment: Dear user234559: you have my deepest sypathy!  Actually I didn't post my answer for nearly two days in the hope that someone would come along and give an elementary solution. Since nobody did, I finally decided to write  this solution so that your question didn't remain unanswered, especially since I didn't know your actual  familiarity with algebraic geometry. May I be so bold as to ask which course/book you are following in your first course?

Comment: Dear Georges, I am sorry for my slow response - I had a muddle with my account details! In answer to your question: the course I attended was very geometric in style (a lot of proofs were given by pictures and a lot of algebraic details skipped over) - so I am working at a very elementary level - just the basic definitions and a solid grasp of linear algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you are now Elliptic2005 because of your muddle ?

Comment: Yes - that's right :)